# Downsampling 3D array with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Given array:

```
A = array([[[1, 2, 3, 1],
            [4, 5, 6, 2],
            [7, 8, 9, 3]]])
```

I obtain the following array in the forward pass with a downsampling factor of `k-1`:

```
k = 3
B = A[...,::k]

#output  
array([[[1, 1],
        [4, 2],
        [7, 3]]])
```

In the backward pass I want to be able to come back to my original shape, with an output of:

```
array([[[1, 0, 0, 1],
        [4, 0, 0, 2],
        [7, 0, 0, 3]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) to initialize the output and indexing:

```
shape = list(B.shape)
shape[-1] = k*(shape[-1]-1)+1
# [1, 3, 4]

A2 = np.zeros(shape, dtype=B.dtype)
A2[..., ::k] = B

print(A2)
```

output:

```
array([[[1, 0, 0, 1],
        [4, 0, 0, 2],
        [7, 0, 0, 3]]])
```

##### using `A`:

```
A2 = np.zeros_like(A)
A2[..., ::k] = B
# or directly
# A2[..., ::k] = A[..., ::k]
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway, this is working on k=3, whenever k is changed it won't work yet both B and A2 depends on that k. for example if k =2

output B = (array([[[1, 3],
         [4, 6],
         [7, 9]]])
and I want A2 to be 
(array([[[1, 0,3,0],
         [4,0, 6,0],
         [7,0, 9,0]]]). So in short, I want something whatever the number of k, it will work. Thanks

Comment: @AverageLeaner there was a mistake, check again

Comment: However it's impossible to make trailing columns of 0 just by knowing B and k. You can force the output shape (like even, multiple of k, or whatever, but you can never predict back the exact original shape with trailing data)

Comment: I see what you mean, but you still have access to original array A, right? and the idea is to get to the original shape of A

Comment: If you still have `A`, then no problem. I'll update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248551/discussion-between-average-leaner-and-mozway).